# Time and Work Problems::

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A,B and C work at different speeds.when they slowest two work together
>   they take x days to finish the Job.when the quickest two of the three
>   work together they take y days to finish the Job.one of them working
>   alone takes three times time taken when all of the three work
>   together.Find the time taken to finish the job when all the three work
>   together.

```
I have tried:

let the speeds of A,B,C be a,b,c
```

**From this question which two i consider fastest , two as slowest and working alone.**

Please guide me on how should one go about solving
    this and such other related problems involving time-work
    constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider $A < B < C $ in terms of efficiency. Thus, $B $ and $C $ complete the work in $x $ days and $A $ and $B $ do it in $y $ days.

If the quickest one is only one-third as efficient as the entire team, the other two cannot add up to two-thirds. By a similar logic, the slowest one cannot be the person who is one-third as efficient.

So, $B $ is one third efficient giving us that if the three complete the work in $k $ days, $B $ alone will do it in $3k$ days.

We have $B $ and $C $ complete $\frac {1}{x}$ part of work in a day and $A $ and $B $ complete $\frac {1}{y} $ part in a day. We also have $B $ does $\frac {1}{3k} $ part of work in a day.

So, $A,B $ and $C $ do $\frac {1}{x}+\frac {1}{y}-\frac {1}{3k} $ work in one day. (Why?) This is equal to $\frac {1}{k} $ as all three take $k $ days to finish the work.

Hope you can take it from here.